# Java: How can I generate a PDF file from a JSP JSF page?

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, icefaces

I need to generate a PDF from a JSP JSF page. I have searched the net, but I didn't found any examples of how should I do this. I need to transform the whole page, or maybe only the charts that I have on that page.

P.S. I'm also using IceFaces.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is probably to [capture the HTML](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) using a [Filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and convert that to PDF using a suitable API, then return the `application/pdf` data from the `Filter`. The IceFaces partial-submit support can probably be used to capture a subset of the component tree output, but you'll probably have to study the details of the IceFaces HTTP requests to figure out how to leverage that.

Comment: That's indeed the way, but it's not as straightforward as it look like. For more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side/1963571#1963571

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this isn't directly possible. You can use [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_tutorial.html) to generate a pdf on the server side. Or, you can use [PrintPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5971) which is a firefox plugin to create one from the web browser.

Comment: +1 for jasper reports, and if you are using jfree chart for you charts, jasper reports will support them, and you can use the same charts in your report/pdf.

Comment: jasper uses iText to generate the PDF - unless there is another reason to use Jasper, it would be better to skip straight to iText

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need the following:

1. Capture the (X)HTML output of your page. This can be done via the following code in a servlet of yours :

   ```
   InputStream is = new URL("http://localhost/foo/page.jsf").openStream();
   ```
2. Transform the captured content to pdf. See the [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) renderer (and additionally - [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf))
3. "Send" the generated pdf. That is, simply write (print) your pdf to the `response.getOutputStream()`, and set a Content-Type header - `response.setContentType("application/pdf")`