# How to save content of a page call into a file in jsp/java?

Tags: java, xml, file, jsp, save

In jsp/java how can you call a page that outputs a xml file as a result and save its result (xml type) into a xml file on server. Both files (the file that produces the xml and the file that we want to save/overwrite) live on the same server.

Basically I want to update my **test.xml** every now and then by calling **generate.jsp** that outputs a xml type result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request is idempotent, then just use [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to get an InputStream of the JSP output. E.g.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/context/page.jsp").openStream();
```

If the request is not idempotent, then you need to replace the [`PrintWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) of the response with a custom implementation which copies the output into some buffer/builder. I've posted a code example here before: [Capture generated dynamic content at server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side/1963571#1963571)

Once having the output, just write it to disk the usual `java.io` way, assuming that JSP's are already in XHTML format.

Comment: What do you mean by 'idempotent'? Also do I need to use the full address in URL or can I just use 'URL("/xml/generate.jsp")' ?

Comment: idempotent = always the same result when invoking a procedure. In HTTP terms, that's how GET works. Sending one URL always give the same result. This isn't the case in POST, because the input/output is not controlled by only the URL. And yes, you of course need the full address. It would otherwise not know where to find it. You can however construct it dynamically based on the methods provided by `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Thanks mate, it seems like it answered my question. Although I haven't been able to write it to the file so I wouldn't know if it actually read the data from the InputStream.
Thanks again.

Comment: You can find basic Java IO tutorial here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/ It isn't that hard, just a `while` loop with a `byte[]` buffer inside a `try-catch-finally` block which reads the inputstream into the buffer and writes the buffer to the outputstream until end of inputstream is reached.

Comment: Yes, I am abale to create the file easily, the issue is just the path issue I have created a new topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046265/trying-to-update-the-file-in-src-web-prod-folder-jsp) For some reason I am not able to create the file in the place I want to. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. Register a filter that adds a wrapper to your response. That is, it returns to the chain a new `HttpServletResponse` objects, extending the original `HttpServletResponse`, and returning your custom `OutputStream` and `PrintWriter` instead of the original ones.
2. Your `OutputStream` and `PrintWriter` calls the original `OutputStream` and `PrintWriter`, but also write to a your file (using a new `FileOutputStream`)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a real template engine like FreeMarker? That would be easier.