# Trying to update the file in src/web/prod folder (jsp)

Tags: java, file, jsp, jboss, path

I am using jboss, eclipse and svn together. I have to files in my test folder: **test/create.jsp** and **test/data.txt** . What I want to do is when I call my **create.jsp** it will update my **data.txt** . Obviously I want my data.txt to stay where it is as other scripts are tryong to read from it.

I have tried dozens of new ways to put the path to my File object but for some reason it creates the file under jboss war folders.

Tried:

```
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
String path1 = app.getRealPath("/");
File f = new File(path1);
// AND
File f = new File("../../data.txt");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `/test` folder is located in the webcontent, then you need the following:

```
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/test/data.txt");
File file = new File(absolutePath);
```

or

```
String webcontentRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File file = new File(webcontentRoot, "test/data.txt");
```

Do you see it? The Java IO only understands local disk file system paths, not URL's or paths outside the context. The `ServletContext#getRealPath()` is to be used to convert a **relative web path** to an **absolute local disk file system path** which in turn can be used further in the usual Java IO stuff. You should *never* use relative paths in Java IO stuff. You will be dependent on the current working directory which may differ per environment/situation.

That said, you normally don't want to write files to the webcontent. They will get lost whenever you redeploy the WAR. Rather create a fixed disk file system path somewhere else outside the webapp and make use of it. Or even better, make use of an independent SQL database :)

Comment: Both absolutePath and webcontentRoot point to one location and its: "C:\workspace\infweb\gen\jboss\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\.\deploy\infweb.war\test\data.txt" which I really want it to be "C:\workspace\infweb\src\web\prod\test.txt" May be I am just confusing the paths and not understanding fully on what happens when you deploy.

lol and yes, if it was in my hand I would have used sql and my life would've been much easier.