# JSF: How to capture response that is send to client

Tags: jsf, serialization, response, capture

I want to implement some kind of help-functionality within my jsf-application

Scenario:

When the users of my app are having problems, they send me screenshots. These are of poor quality and I cannot see the information I want.

My idea: I add a "help"-Button into my jsf-Page. When this button is pressed I store the render-response (resulting html) that is send to client on my hd.

Now I can open that generated html-file and can see the information I want (e.g. values of inputfield)

Now my Question.

How can I perform this task?

I have tried PhaseListener and using

`PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(System.out);
DebugUtil.simplePrintTree(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(),"",w);`

but this is just the component tree and not the resulting html

In other words: I want to capture the output of FacesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse() that is send to client

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture generated dynamic content at server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Filter` around the `FacesServlet`. There define a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and in turn make its `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` return wrappers of the original objects. In the wrappers, in addition to delegating to the original implementation, store the written data somewhere else.