# Render a jsp page from code and get the rendered html output as a string

Tags: java, html, string, jsp

What's the easiest way to make a JSP page render, then get the rendered html content as a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture generated dynamic content at server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` class methods or JSTL `<c:import/>`

Answer (score 10):

There is this tutorial, which explains every step with code:

http://valotas.com/get-output-of-jsp-or-servlet-response/

Doing it this way has advantages when the JSP is not accessible by URL directly.

Comment: In addition you might want to override setContentType(String x) in the from the example. Otherwise forward() might change it for your servlet's response.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide your own wrapper for the `Writer` of `HttpServletResponse` (via `HttpServletResponseWrapper` in a `Filter`), and each time you write to that writer, also store in a `StringBuilder`.

That's just a sketch of the code, there is a sufficient number of examples, but the main steps are:

- create a filter
- wrap `PrintWriter` to make it store each write in a builder
- extend `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and make it return the writer wrapper
- create `chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response))`